# How do I start the Kubelet with a static pod kube api server?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I am trying to build a kubernetes master with kubelet and kube-api server running as a static pod.

My unit for kubelet is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet \
  --cloud-provider=external \
  --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml \
  --network-plugin=cni \
  --register-node=false \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig.yaml \
  --v=2

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the kubelet I see the following errors:

```
.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes/master-3-tm?resourceVersion=0&timeout=10s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.254850    2584 kubelet_node_status.go:391] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "master-3-tm": Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes/master-3-tm?timeout=10s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.255466    2584 kubelet_node_status.go:391] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "master-3-tm": Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes/master-3-tm?timeout=10s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.255956    2584 kubelet_node_status.go:391] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "master-3-tm": Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes/master-3-tm?timeout=10s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.256403    2584 kubelet_node_status.go:391] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "master-3-tm": Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes/master-3-tm?timeout=10s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.256696    2584 kubelet_node_status.go:379] Unable to update node status: update node status exceeds retry count
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: W1125 15:40:14.604686    2584 cni.go:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Nov 25 15:40:14 master-3-tm kubelet[2584]: E1125 15:40:14.604828    2584 kubelet.go:2110] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

Which make sense, because the kube-api server is still not running. But the question is how do I get it to running?

I have the following manifests:

```
root@master-3-tm:/home/ubuntu# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-api-server.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --advertise-address=10.32.192.20
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --audit-log-maxage=30
    - --audit-log-maxbackup=3
    - --audit-log-maxsize=100
    - --audit-log-path=/var/log/kubernetes/audit.log
    - --bind-address=10.32.192.20
    - --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem
    - --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
    - --cloud-provider=openstack
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,NodeRestriction,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/api-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/api-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=master-1-tm=https://10.32.192.69:2380,master-3-tm=https://10.32.192.20:2380,master-2-tm=https://10.32.192.76:2380
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-certificate-authority=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem
    - --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem
    - --kubelet-https=true
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/service-accounts.pem
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.32.0.0/16
    - --service-node-port-range=30000-32767
    - --runtime-config=api/all
    - --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/api.cert
    - --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem
    - --token-auth-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/token.csv
    - --v=2
    - --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.11.4
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 10.32.192.20
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/lib/kubernetes
      readOnly: true
      name: var-lib-kubernetes
    - mountPath: /var/log/kubernetes
      name: var-log-kubernetes
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/kuberentes
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/log/kuberentes
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
status: {}
root@master-3-tm:/home/ubuntu# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: etcd
    tier: control-plane
  name: etcd
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - etcd
    - --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
    - --client-cert-auth=true
    - --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
    - --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
    - --peer-client-cert-auth=true
    - --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
    - --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --snapshot-count=10000
    - --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    env:
      - name: ETCD_NAME
        value: master-3-tm
      - name: ETCD_DATA_DIR
        value: /var/lib/data
      - name: ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE
        value: new
      - name: ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN
        value: k8s-cluster
      - name: ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER
        value: master-1-tm=https://10.32.192.69:2380,master-3-tm=https://10.32.192.20:2380,master-2-tm=https://10.32.192.76:2380
      - name: ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS
        value: https://10.32.192.20:2379
      - name: ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS
        value: https://10.32.192.20:2380
      - name: ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS
        value: https://10.32.192.20:2379
      - name: ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS
        value: https://10.32.192.20:2380
    image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.3.10
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -ec
        - ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
          --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
          get foo
      failureThreshold: 8
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: etcd
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
      name: etcd-data
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
      name: etcd-certs
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etcd-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/etcd
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etcd-data
status: {}
```

Oddly, kubelet will start etcd, but not the api server...

Also worth noting:

```
 * the kubelet isn't trying to register, at least according to the flag:
   Nov 25 15:50:43 master-3-tm kubelet[3440]: I1125 15:50:43.578457    3440 flags.go:27] FLAG: --register-node="false"
Nov 25 15:50:43 master-3-tm kubelet[3440]: I1125 15:50:43.578464    3440 flags.go:27] FLAG: --register-schedulable="true"
Nov 25 15:50:43 master-3-tm kubelet[3440]: I1125 15:50:43.578471    3440 flags.go:27] FLAG: --register-with-taints=""
```

How do I start the api pod before the kubelet service? or how do I find why kubelet won't start that specific pod?

#### update

The kubelet should find the static pods in the correct place:

```
ubuntu@master-3-tm:~$ grep manifests /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml 
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

Comment: You're also **for sure** going to want to fix that CNI error, or your cluster will continue to be sickly

Comment: I didn't bother with installing a CNI plugin, because my cluster seemed broken. There is no API server to feed the CNI plugin too ...

Comment: CNI is not related to the API server, but if you're not going to use CNI, you will need every Pod you launch to have an IP that every other Pod you launch can reach; ironically, there is a CNI plugin that will use your LAN's DHCP server for that purpose

Comment: I still don't get how this helps me understand how to solve the chicken egg problem.. The apiserver runs with   hostNetwork: true, so it should be available

Comment: there is no chicken and egg problem; kubelet is a standalone binary that _will_ execute the PodSpec files specified in the manifests directory. If your apiserver is not starting, you'll need to include the error message from **it** if you expect anyone to help you

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know why there is not error message. etcd would start and I can see the logs with docker. But for the api server there is no container.

Comment: Not even in `docker ps -a`? that is, it never even _attempts_ to start one? If you're going to get more help, you're going to have to post more than just a few lines of your kubelet logs

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for not giving up. I actually solved the issue, but have not got around to post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all too often, the problem is in detail ...

The faulty line is:

```
- --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
```

Without this file, which is missing, because I forgot to mount the proper volume, kube-apiserver will fail to start.

This will show in the kubelet logs, but is very easy to miss since there are so many messages.

The error is:

```
Nov 29 11:43:08 master-1-test3 kubelet[2645]: F1129 11:43:08.602166    2645 plugins.go:122] Couldn't open cloud provider configuration /etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf: &os.PathError{Op:"open", Path:"/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf", Err:0x2}
```